# Spring web-socket incompatible with jetty9.3

Tags: websocket, jetty, spring-websocket, jetty-9

we are using spring websockets in our application..
Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
<version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And we are using jetty with container as our server.We were using jetty-distribution-9.3.8.v20160314 (container)

And inside configuration we need to provide the jetty upgraderequest JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy so for that in our application we have included jetty-server as dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
<artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
<version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

But here the jetty version was

```
<jetty.version>9.2.1.v20140609</jetty.version>
```

Issue: In jetty there was some native memory related issue..
we suspect the root cause for that

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/293

So we are planning to update the pom dependency to jetty version : 9.3.11.v20160721 and even planning to upgrade the container to the latest.

Our configuration code is as follows:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketBehavior;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketPolicy;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.jetty.JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.DefaultHandshakeHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebSocketConfigurer {


    private static final String NOTIFIER_ENDPOINT_URL = "/notificationHandler";

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(socketHandler(), NOTIFIER_ENDPOINT_URL).setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler socketHandler() {
        return new NotificationSocketHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultHandshakeHandler handshakeHandler() {

        WebSocketPolicy policy = new WebSocketPolicy(WebSocketBehavior.SERVER);
        policy.setInputBufferSize(8192);
        policy.setIdleTimeout(600000);

        return new DefaultHandshakeHandler(new JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy(new WebSocketServerFactory(policy)));
    }

}
```

There were some unit test cases for our application which were running fine with earlier versions of spring and websocket server .But if i update the maven version then test cases are failing with following stack.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:183)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:123)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:149)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:517)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:140)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:170)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:104)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1199)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1124)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1032)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:205)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:108)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:111)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webSocketHandlerMapping'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize Jetty WebSocketServerFactory
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:852)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:133)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:183)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:123)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:149)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:517)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:140)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:170)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:104)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1199)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1124)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1032)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:205)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:108)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:111)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize Jetty WebSocketServerFactory
at org.springframework.web.socket.server.jetty.JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy.start(JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy.java:164)
at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.AbstractHandshakeHandler.doStart(AbstractHandshakeHandler.java:204)
at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.AbstractHandshakeHandler.start(AbstractHandshakeHandler.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.start(WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHandlerMapping.start(WebSocketHandlerMapping.java:65)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:852)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:133)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:183)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:123)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:149)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:517)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:140)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:170)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:104)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1199)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1124)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1032)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:205)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:108)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:111)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, WebSocket support unavailable
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory.init(WebSocketServerFactory.java:393)
at org.springframework.web.socket.server.jetty.JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy.start(JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.AbstractHandshakeHandler.doStart(AbstractHandshakeHandler.java:204)
at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.AbstractHandshakeHandler.start(AbstractHandshakeHandler.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.start(WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHandlerMapping.start(WebSocketHandlerMapping.java:65)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:852)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:133)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:183)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:123)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:149)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:517)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:140)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:170)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:104)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1199)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1124)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1032)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:205)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:108)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:111)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

Our test case setup for server is as follows:

```
@BeforeClass
    public void setup() throws Exception {

        this.wsUrl = WS_URI;
        // manager = new WebSocketConnectionManager(client, new
        // NotificationSocketHandler(), this.wsUrl);
        client.start();
        server = new Server();
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setPort(PORT);
        server.addConnector(connector);
        server.setHandler(new org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketHandler() {
            @Override
            public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
                factory.setCreator(new WebSocketCreator() {
                    @Override
                    public Object createWebSocket(ServletUpgradeRequest req, ServletUpgradeResponse resp) {
                        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(req.getSubProtocols())) {
                            resp.setAcceptedSubProtocol(req.getSubProtocols().get(0));
                        }
                        JettyWebSocketSession session = new JettyWebSocketSession(null, null);
                        // return new JettyWebSocketHandlerAdapter(new
                        // NotificationSocketHandler(), session);
                        return new JettyWebSocketHandlerAdapter(notificationSocketHandler, session);
                    }

                });
            }
        });
        server.start();

        LOGGER.info("Is Server started : {}",server.isStarted());
    }
```

I saw similar stacks in spring websocket build which was fixed

```
https://build.spring.io/browse/SPR-PERF-JOB1-524/test/case/155371676;jsessionid=5AB904EDAC4CF61463961C5CF88A6B1A

https://build.spring.io/browse/SPR-PERF-526
```

Comment: This was addressed as part of https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13162

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt..The change made as part of jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13162 is internal to spring? or configuration changes must be made in application?..It would be really helpful if u could please let me what changes exactly needs to be done..We are upgrading the spring websocket version to 4.3.2 Release and apart from upgrading spring websockets should there be any configuration change in the above class mentioned.or changes should be in test case class mentioned above?.Thanks in advance